# Macro to compare workbooks for VBA- Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA for excel. I would like to create a macro to compare two separate Workbooks, then show the differences between them. For more detail i will say that the only thing that needs to be compared are Column A in both of the workbooks. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/777/getting-started-with-excel-vba#t=201705300004209262522

Comment: Excel 2013+ comes with Spreadsheet Compare tool https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Basic-tasks-in-Spreadsheet-Compare-f2b20af8-a6d3-4780-8011-f15b3229f5d8

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want!!

```
Public Sub CompareSheets()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Set ws1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\your_path_here\Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\your_path_here\Book2.xlsx").Sheets(1)
Set rng = ws1.Range("A1:A20")
For Each cell In rng
    Celladdress = cell.Address
    If cell <> ws2.Range(Celladdress) Then
        cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        ws2.Range(Celladdress).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This just highlights column A spreadsheet 1 of each workbook though, right? It is not comparing the sheets when I run it.